# Closing socket HttpClient in bean (CloseableHttpClient) - need to do this? JAVA

Tags: java, spring, sockets, httpclient, javabeans

Should I worry about to release a socket allocated by **clientBuilder.build()** in this code:

```
@Bean("proxyRestTemplate")
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate proxyRestTemplate() {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(proxyUrl, proxyPort),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword)
        );
        HttpHost myProxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl, proxyPort);
        HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        clientBuilder.setProxy(myProxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).disableCookieManagement();
        HttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new CustomHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(basicAuthUsername, basicAuthPassword));
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

I sincerely hope this will be a short and simple question

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You should close everything that is closeable, but there is no socket here, only an HttpClient.

Comment: ok, but fortify told me that the function proxyRestTemplate() in ProxyConfig.java sometimes fails to release a socket allocated by build()